# SQL 3 IDs Change Over Time

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a logic question which I've been stuck on for a while.

Suppose there is one customer that can be serviced in two separate places, for place A they receive A_ID and place B they receive B_ID. There is a 3rd ID which I will call C_ID which links the two customers together to give a holistic view if they are on both platforms. The customers can be buying from place A only, place B only, or place A and B at the same time.

I want to create a volatile table to back fill populating with A_ID, B_ID, C_ID, on all days if if they are not null.

Currently the data can look like any of the following in the same table:

```
EXAMPLE A 
Date    ,     A_ID   ,     B_ID      ,     C_ID
---------------------------------------------
01/01/17   ,   145   ,               ,    
02/01/17   ,   145   ,               ,
03/01/17   ,   145   ,    201501     ,     601888
04/01/17   ,   145   ,    201502     ,     601888
05/01/17   ,   145   ,    201502     ,     601888
```

OR

```
EXAMPLE B
Date    ,     A_ID   ,     B_ID      ,     C_ID
---------------------------------------------
01/01/17   ,   198   ,               ,    
02/01/17   ,   198   ,               ,
03/01/17   ,   198   ,               ,     
04/01/17   ,   198   ,               ,     
05/01/17   ,   198   ,               ,
```

OR

```
EXAMPLE C
Date    ,     A_ID   ,     B_ID      ,     C_ID
---------------------------------------------
01/01/17   ,         ,     567222          ,    
02/01/17   ,         ,     567222          ,
03/01/17   ,         ,     567222          ,     
04/01/17   ,         ,     567222          ,     
05/01/17   ,         ,     567222          ,
```

I tried a window function:

```
SELECT 
calendar_date,
MAX(A_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY C_ID)      A_ID,
MAX(B_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY C_ID)      B_ID,
MAX(C_ID) OVER(PARTITION BY B_ID,A_ID) C_ID,
FROM TABLE A
```

However this removes all examples which have not yet used both platforms, i.e. example B and example C will not show.

Any ideas?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the purpose of back filling the data? Is it just to ensure you have all their IDs available in every row?

Comment: There are scripts that run a lookback view at each customer later in the process for customer segmentation and analysis - without consistent IDs for each customer in all months previous erroneous results are produced

Comment: So yes - just to be clear, I want all "their" IDs to show in everyone. I.E. if a customer has B_ID NOT NULL in the future but NULL in the past, I want that NOT NULL value to show in the past.

And thank you!

Comment: What result do you expect when there's no id for a place, e.g. `B_ID` and  `C_ID` in example B?

Comment: Hi @dnoeth thanks for your input - I would expect NULL.

Comment: I don't understand what you try to get. You must have another column indicating the customer, why don't you simply use this for PARTITION instead of `A_ID`, etc. Can you add some more cases and expected result?

Comment: Hi @dnoeth thanks for sticking with me here.

The customer is identified by a combination of IDs. If they have only ever been customers to place A they only have A_ID, until the day the sign up to place B, where they will have B_ID and C_ID from that day forward (as in Example A). I want to populate that B_ID and C_ID back to the start of any interaction with that customer.

Comment: If the IDs for a customer never change it's a simple `max(A_ID) over (partition by customerid)`, etc.